# Writing DWORD to end of file on Windows

Tags: c, windows

I am trying to figure out how to write a integer value to the end of my file. The value is `size`.

```
DWORD size = 12314432;
BOOL ret = WriteFile(hFile, size, sizeof(DWORD), NULL, NULL);
```

However `WriteFile()` requires that parameter 3 be of type `LPCVOID` so I am not sure how I would give it the DWORD instead.

I have tried..

```
unsigned char b[sizeof(DWORD)] = {0};
sprintf(b, "%d", size);
WriteFile(hFile, b, sizeof(DWORD), NULL, NULL);
```

However this just puts the hex value of each digit. So if size=1234 then it would write "31 32 33 44" to end of the file.

I would like the end of the file to just get the number in 4 bytes.

Comment: Just to be clear: the 4 bytes of `size` have an order in memory, is that the same order you want on disk?

Answer (score 2):

You provide *the address* of the DWORD like this:

```c
DWORD size = 12314432;
BOOL ret = WriteFile(hFile, &size, sizeof size, NULL, NULL);
```

- Use the ampersand to get the address of the DWORD variable.
- Express your intend for the size, you want to write all of `size`, so say so.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `(void*)&size`. You do need something which has an address, like `size`. You can't pass an expression there. `(void*) &(5*7+3)` won't work.

Comment: The `(void*)` in `(void*)&size` isn't necessary. `&size` will  be implicitely converted to `(void*)`.